# How to make dashed thick lines with dots in ChartJS ? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I try to find in documentation this functionality. I know how to set dotted or dashed line but their combination i cant find.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dotted line can be drawn by adding this `borderDash: [10, 10]` property to each dataset in line charts. You can see the below code or fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/fcwbjy57/

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',              
            borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderDash: [10, 10],
            fill: false
        },{
            label: '# of Votes1',
            data: [17, 9, 13, 9, 20, 13],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',              
            borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderDash: [10, 10],
            fill: false
        },{
            label: '# of Votes2',
            data: [1, 6, 13, 12, 20, 5],
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',               
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderDash: [10, 10],
            fill: false
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: it's not what i need